# How to extract sample from a wav file while keeping original bitrate from terminal

Tags: audio, terminal, extract, sampling, sox

I'm trying to extract some samples from a wav file. I want to keep file format, bitrate etc., so I want to do this without dithering and any other processing. I tried to use sox `trim`.

`sox STE-024.wav ../../raw/1/sample1.wav trim 02:18.155 02:30.625`

It is almost what I expected, but unfortunately it removes the part I want I extract from the original file. I want to keep the original file untouched.

Do you know a way to do what I want using sox, or do you know any other tool that fits better to my needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)

`ffmpeg -i yourfile.wav -ss [start_time] -to [end_time] -c copy output.wav`

A real life example looks like

`ffmpeg -i sample4.wav -ss 10 -to 20 -c copy itwork.wav`

`itwork.wav` file contains the audio content from 10 second to 20 second of the `sample4.wav` file